# How can I navigate a webbrowser programmatically?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to Navigate my web browser with a defined function like:

```
webbrowser1.navigate (my defined function);
```

This webbrowser is defined in a user control so that any one can change its default web page

How can I define a function by which the path sets?

Comment: asked 4 questions and none the answer is accepted yet.

Comment: Sorry pal you are right,but when I test the code I come up empty

Comment: Ok,You know,I've been using this website recently and somehow I don't know the customs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
HtmlElementCollection ele = this.webBrowserControl.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Form");  

foreach(HtmlElement currentElement in ele)
{
    currentElement.InvokeMember("submit");
}
```

OR

```
webbrowser.Document.All["ID OF ELEMENT"].InvokeMember("click");
```

Hope Its helpful.

Comment: you mean I do not need to use something like webbowser1.navigate(somestring)?
imagine you do not know the html file's name

Comment: you know some how its a usercontrol which is supposed to be add to a program

Comment: :yeah,but its string is supposed to be changeable

Comment: can you paste important part of your code, so that exact help can be given

Comment: public string LoadHTMLFilePath
        {
            get
            {
                string filepath = "";
                return filepath;
            }
            set
            {
                string filepath;
                filepath = value;
                
            }
If this document returns the string of navigation my problem will be solved

Comment: Ohh, It will require to debugg your application and see from where actually values are comming and how they are got set to it.

Comment: Actually i am sorry, i could not provide you exact help.